Is it correct to say "arrange the cup side by side in a row"?
According to my study, to arrange cups in a row means the face of each facing forward like this

But this way of arrangement takes up too much space, so people arrange them like this

But to describe the above picture correctly, do we have to say
"arrange the cup side by side in a row" means the face of each facing the same direction.
Is it correct to say "arrange the cup side by side in a row" for the 2nd picture?

I wouldn't understand 'in a row' to imply any particular orientation of the cups (though people standing in a row would be assumed to be facing forwards).

@KateBunting, so that is why I added "side by side in a row", which means all the cups facing the same direction.

If people are standing in a row, it's quite possible that some of them are facing in the opposite direction to others because they're talking to their friend who is also in the "queue". And nothing says people in a queue have to face forwards anyway. Obviously if you're placing cups in a row the handles are all likely to face the same way because your hand normally holds them from the same side as they're being put down. Unless you're ambidextrously using both hands, in which case feasibly the side with the handle might naturally alternate as you position them.

@FumbleFingers - True - I was thinking of a row as being different from a line or queue, but I suppose it isn't necessarily. Anyway, does a round cup or mug have 'sides' in that sense?

"Please line the cups up neatly" might reasonably be assumed to mean the handles should all be in the same orientation. But that's only an assumption - English doesn't have special constructions to succinctly describe situations where multiple similar objects are placed in some clearly-defined relationship to each other, like the atoms in a crystal lattice. Except maybe some domain-specific terms in crystallography that are well outside the scope of this site.

@KateBunting: I suppose you could distinguish the handle side from the opposite side for a cup. I can't think of any more specific term for the "non-handle side". But with no other context, my natural assumption for "the cup's opposite side" would be modeled on the other side of the Moon (the side we can't see). Since I'm right-handed, I might refer to text as being written on "the opposite side of the cup" - meaning the side you see (but I don't) if we're sitting opposite each other drinking our coffee, and my cup has a witty follow-up to the text written on my side!

...I certainly don't accept OP's implication that the side of a cup directly opposite the handle should be called the "face" of the cup. It's only relevant when there's something (text or picture) printed on the cup, and in that situation probably the primary "face" would be the one facing away from a right-handed drinker. But this is all guesswork - there are no fixed commonly-understood terms to distinguish the "visible to drinker", "visible to onlooker", and "opposite to handle" sides of cups.

@Tom There is no special meaning that accrues to "in a row" or "side by side" when mugs have handles. Most people would understand "in a row" and "side-by-side" both to mean adjacent to one another, i.e. so that no mug is even partially in front of another.  Handles won't come into play unless they're mentioned.

I would suggest that cups would normally be stored / displayed in such a way that the handles were facing outwards, towards the potential users, to make picking them up again easier. This might be described as "lining them up"

There are a hundred ways to describe your picture.  I would say, Line the mugs up from the front of the table to the back, with the handles on the righthand side at two o'clock.  Leave about a half an inch space between each mug.  Voting to close as opinion based.

@FumbleFingers - I'm reminded of the old joke where 'a bloke' talks about the 'front' of a tree, and he is asked 'How do you know that's the "front"?' and he replies 'Well, someone's had a crap round the back'.

@MichaelHarvey: Lol. I can see that by this time next year, my AI-enabled browser will have changed my "Therapeutic Laugh of the Day" favourites link to whatever chatgpt thinks was your best contribution from the last 24 hours!

"In a row" means a single line of cups,  it says nothing about which way the handles face.
You can describe the photo as "cups arranged in a row".
Since the cups are basically round, I wouldn't particularly identify a "front" or "back".  Often the "picture" on a mug is arranged so as to be facing out when the cup is held in the right hand.  So the picture is on the "side" not the "front".
I don't think you ever need to describe how to arrange cups. It's pretty obvious, and if someone needs to be told, they are probably so young that they need to be shown.
So "In a row" is sufficient for all practical purposes.

We could say
Arrange the cups in a row horizontally and with handles towards you.
or
Arrange the cups in a row (or 'column') vertically
in front of you and with handles towards the right (or 'left').
This is less likely if there are many cups.
Side by side is redundant.

“Arrange the cups in a row across you” is not grammatical, nor is it clear what “across you” would mean.  A vertical row of cups would seem to imply a stack of cups, rather than a side by side configuration.

Thanks, @Juhasz.  I have replaced across you with horizontally.
